# Polymer <more-routing> how can I set attribute value of another element using routing params

Tags: polymer

I have just stepped into Polymer. At the moment I am trying to use more-route library to switch between elements. The polycast from Rob Dodson is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-67kb7poIT8&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN&index=4). The basic concept of declarative route is well understood and I can make it to work.

But my requirement is slightly different. I have created two elements:

```
<customer-list>
```

> This prases a JSON string and displays a list of customers I have. Every JSON record is associated with a CustomerId.

```
<contact-info>
```

> A JSON string is involved here as well which has a list of contact information each mapped up with a CustomerId.

I have an attribute (`custid`) set in my contact-info element, i.e. `attributes="custid"`.

What I want is to click on a customer from customer-list element and invoke a route something like `/customers/50`. This `50` needs to be set in `{{custid}}` attribute of contact-info element. And finally based on this Customer Id, Polymer would parse and pick up the contact(s) from the JSON string. Once it gets it the following snippet:

```
<template repeat={{c in contacts}}></template>
```

would bind the list of contacts for Customer Id 50. I have no idea how to set an attribute value of another using route parameters. Seeking for expert help. I tried on Google but unfortunately could not find a suitable answer!

The following screenshot might help to understand what exactly I am looking for!

[image]

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Routes.HTML

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/more-routing/more-routing.html"/>
<more-routing-config driver="hash"></more-routing-config>
<more-route name="home" path="/"></more-route>
<more-route name="customers" path="/customers">
    <more-route name="customer-contact" path="/:custext"></more-route>
</more-route>
```

Index.html (core-menu)

```html
<more-route-selector>
  <core-menu selected="0">
    <core-item label="Home" route="home">
      <a href="{{urlFor('home')}}"></a>
    </core-item>
    <core-item label="Customers" route="customers">
      <a href="{{urlFor('customers')}}"></a>
    </core-item>
  </core-menu>
</more-route-selector>
```

Index.html (main section)

```html
<more-route-selector selectedParams="{{params}}">
  <core-pages>
    <section route="home">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <div>This is the home section</div>
    </section>
    <section route="customers">
      <h1>Customers</h1>
      <div>This is customers section</div>
    </section>
  </core-pages>
</more-route-selector>
```

Output (Screenshot)
[image]

Tested in both

```html
Chrome (42.0.2311.135 m) and Firefox (37.0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to bind to the `selectedParams` property of the `more-routing` element. I explain it a bit toward the end of the polycast: https://youtu.be/-67kb7poIT8?t=3m15s

Comment: This time I did exactly what the Polycast says! But all the sections under core-pages are visible when page loads or when I click on a link. Page contents are not switching amongst themselves like it does in the Polycast. What wrong I am doing? I have edited my original question to put the code snippet. Help!

Comment: Oh! Silly mistake. Sorry for the big Edit. I forgot to reference core-pages.html in my elements.html! Switching between pages and their contents are now working fine. selectedParams section is still not working for me yet though. +1 to the Polycast :-)

Comment: Hi Rob. Finally I have the situation where I need your help. Two elements I have one of which (customer-list) is rendering URLs like http://localhost:9000/#!/customers/cyfox for each customer, where "cyfox" is the key which I want to grab in another element (customer-detail). Based on this value I will parse a JSON and display information. How can I do this? I may be posting silly question even after seeing the video. Hope you will consider me as a newbie to Polymer! An example would be nice :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Polycast from Rob Dodson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-67kb7poIT8&index=5&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN) on YouTube, and [answer from Ian McLeod in Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/polymer-dev/RFcINWg-p2s/-lfyu3z91WAJ).

The code snippet looks like this:

Index.html

```html
<section route="customer-detail">
  <post-card>
    <h2>Our branches</h2>
    <div><customer-detail route="customer-detail" cname="{{params.cust}}"></customer-detail></div>
    <footer><a href="{{urlFor('customers')}}">Bck to list</a></footer>
  </post-card>
</section>
```

Customer-detail.html

```html
<customer-detail>
```

```html
<polymer-element name="customer-detail" attributes="cname fullname">
  <template>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="customer-detail.css">
      <template repeat="{{c in customers}}">
          <template repeat="{{b in c.branches}}" if="{{c.cuname == cname}}">
              <div class="single-customer-info">
                  <h1>{{b.branch}} (Code: {{b.code}})</h1>
                  <p>
                      {{b.address}}. Phone: {{b.phone}}<br/>
                  </p>
                  <h1><a href="mailto:{{b.email}}">{{b.email}}</a></h1>
              </div>
          </template>
      </template>
  </template>
```

And finally the routes.html

```html
<more-route name="customers" path="/customers">
    <more-route name="customer-detail" path="/:cust"></more-route>
</more-route>
```

Hope this will help others.